# Set path for Apache POI

Tags: java, linux, apache-poi

I want to create excel file and write data in that file using java program.

That is [here](http://www.techbrainwave.com/?p=554) and i extracted Apache POI in location where java file is present.and include that path in path variable.

when i try to compile its giving following error:

```
data.java:3: package org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
                                    ^
data.java:4: package org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
                                    ^
data.java:5: package org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRichTextString;
                                    ^
data.java:6: package org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
                                    ^
data.java:7: package org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
                                    ^
data.java:8: package org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
                                    ^
data.java:11: package org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
                                    ^
data.java:12: package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
                              ^
```

this is list of Poi files.in this which one i have to include ?

```
root@:[/u01/isac/code/CWSA/isac/java/exportAPI/poi-3.9]

$ ll    

total 9044    

-rw-r--r--  1 root root   27138 Nov 25 15:23 LICENSE    
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     890 Nov 25 15:23 NOTICE    
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root    4096 Nov 26 17:22 docs    
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Nov 26 17:22 lib    
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Nov 26 17:22 ooxml-lib    
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1869113 Nov 26 17:22 poi-3.9-20121203.jar    
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  309368 Nov 26 17:22 poi-examples-3.9-20121203.jar    
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   30446 Nov 26 17:22 poi-excelant-3.9-20121203.jar    
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  936648 Nov 26 17:22 poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar    
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4802621 Nov 26 17:22 poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar    
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1226511 Nov 26 17:22 poi-scratchpad-3.9-20121203.jar
```

Comment: are you using an IDE for this project? If yes, which one? All of the IDE's have functionality of adding third party libraries to existing projects, and most of the time they will automatically adjust your classpath.

Comment: add jar apache-poi.jar(3.7) to the buildpath

Comment: i am not using any IDE.and i have set the path javac -cp /u01/isac/code/CWSA/isac/java/exportAPI/poi-3.9/poi-3.9-20121203.jar data.java
in make ..when i try to execute ./make it is showing Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
/u01/isac/code/CWSA/isac/java/exportAPI/poi-3.9/poi-3.9-20121203.jar

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the jar location in the *-cp* option of javac:

```
javac -cp /path/to/your/jar/poi-<version>.jar data.java
```

Besides, you may want to use a build tool to manage your dependency, e.g. [maven](http://maven.apache.org) or [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) for ant.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the jar files (poi lib) in your classpath, not the same directory with your data.java. (btw, it should be Data.java). Because you very likely have your own package structure, like `com.myapp`.

And the PATH variable has nothing to do with java classpath. it makes no difference if you set or unset it.